# best practices to return Boolean value from function- Hardcode or from variable

Tags: python, boolean

**Which is best practices to return Boolean value from a function:**

1. Hardcoded
2. as a variable

**Code 1** :

```
    (status, response) = self.generate_pdf(html_data)
    if not status:
        return (False, response)
```

**Code 2**:

```
    (status, response) = self.generate_pdf(html_data)
    if not status:
        return (status, response)
```

According to me returning hardcode value (`False` or `True`) is good.

[More details]
I always return two parameter from every function, `status` and `response`. A `status` is Boolean object i.e. value is `True` or `False`. A `response` is dictionary object.

As `status` have a value `False` i.e. `status` is referring address of `False`.

```
>>> id(False)
493227104
>>> status = False
>>> id(status')
493227104
```

So returning reference variable name is good practices or  actual bool value ?

Comment: I'd say it depends on the values that ``status`` can take. More information about your class is needed.

Answer (score 7):

This question is quite opinion based, but I would point out a difference between the two approaches: the `if not status` condition will happen if `status` is any false-y - an actual `False`, a `0`, `None`, etc.

The first approach will always return `False`. The second will retain whatever original false-y caused the condition to evaluate. Whether the first or the second is more appropriate depends on your program and some more context that wasn't provided in the question.

Comment: Thank you,  I agree. Added few details in question. So returning reference variable name is good practices or actual bool value ?